# Please read complaints of rep 1 users more carefully

Tags: discussion

**Edit:**

#### My apologies to Karl Richter and Waltinator!

**This post was not meant as an attack on you personally *at all*** but more of a "call to arms" to the community at large to try and understand that there are humans behind an avatar and that most people are nice and are willing to help one another!<sup>*</sup>

The following answer:

[image]

was actually talking about [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/937325/344926) that contained a [malicious link](https://askubuntu.com/posts/937325/revisions).

So next time when you see a N00b complaining about links, open the entire Q&A in another tab and *add a bit of extra Sherlock Holmes to your thinking process*...

## :-)

<sup>*</sup> I've been told that this post could be interpreted in a negative way, but that was totally not my goal...  Do I owe you more than an apology? Beer? Pizza? A bounty on one of your answers???  **:-)**

Comment: Better suggestion: Newbies need a guide for how to handle such bad things, and how to properly report them.  **AND** that has to be presented to them before they can even post anything.  Like a second "Welcome to the site, read this first" notice.

Comment: "pretend it's an audit" - audits aren't important - real posts are important! Also, agreeing with Thomas Ward, the answerer should have suggested an edit to remove the link (or flagged if they were able). I am endlessly frustrated by reviewers of FP & LA doing nothing, but I consider such detective work a little too much to expect (nice if it gets done, but above and beyond). As far as I can see, this post was treated properly (flagged as NAA by FP/LA reviewers, looks like, and deleted by the community) and your helpful action to follow up & fix the post it mentioned was great but exceptional

Comment: I agree with both of you that the policy, process and product should be changed, but I disagree that any of those Ps should be Primordial. **;-)**  In my world, the People are most important, then the Policy, then the Process and then the Product...  (I also listened and removed reference to the audit process)

Comment: @Fabby Remind me again how I was involved here, please (I remember the post, so I might be...). That being said, there's obviously no harm being done. Also, I don't get your post/question. Do you mean that you posted this as user guest? The post raises valid points, but omitting post with links to sites with links to data monsters is a harsh policy ultimately resulting in endless discussion which can't take place in or under the answer.

Comment: Nah, It's a user who posted this, and you just voted to delete as it was *really unclear*  what he was blabbering on about and I found that he was trying to leave a comment on another answer (that contained a malicious link)  And then someone pinged me in chat that this Q micht be construed as a personal attack on you because you did the logical thing and I did the illogical thing...  **;-)** @KarlRichter

Comment: P.S. As you can't see deleted answers [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsDiN.png)'s what it looks like now... @KarlRichter  So I just wanted to apologize if you were offended by  my comment at the time or the question here...  *I try to be nice all the time, but I fail regularly...* **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @Fabby Who doesn't - do both these things... There's no need apologize; the attempt and verification is appreciated. However, I still didn't get: Was there really a malious link (which I'd say is malware which directly damages a system) or did guest1 refer to Facebook and Google as malious (probably not without reason, however with a too broad use of the attribute)?

Comment: Big red FireFox warning of a link that used to be the SourceForge of its time (CodeIndustry).  @KarlRichter

Comment: @Fabby I see, I'm sure the link was edited already, when I reviewed it (I remember opening it in a VirtualBox VM), so I assumed the user was talking about the Facebook links on the correct site exclusively.

Comment: That Google feature is very useful actually! **:D >:D :P**

Comment: @ThomasWard What's the correct channel to report things like this before earning 15 rep for voting and flagging?

Comment: @DamianYerrick You mean to report potential malicious links? A mod flag would work. Or propose an edit to remove the malicious link and indicate in the edit reason that a link is no longer valid or safe

Comment: @ThomasWard Then they'll have to suggest edits, as users below 15 rep cannot flag.

Comment: @DamianYerrick this is why I said "Or propose an edit".